# Getting 404 error code while using the HTTP endpoint to the Bot on Gupshup platform

Tags: chatbot, gupshup

I am creating a chatbot using Gupshup platform and they have a HTTP endpoint to the bot using which I can configure the bot to take different actions like sending notification on different intervals.

But when I am calling the below HTTP endpoint

> https://www.gupshup.io/developer/bot/homesbot/public?text=Hello

I get this error -

`{"code":404,"message":"Kindly register listener for Http Endpoint : /public"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define this function to handle the endpoint in your bot

```
function HttpEndpointHandler(context, event){

 }
```

You'l encounter the 404 error if you don't register this function. 
Read [this documentation](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/http-call-to-a-bot) for more details.